# GTK+ 2.0 C weird structure and g_signal_connect_swapped

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gnome, gtk2

I have following declarations:

```
typedef struct window_and_search_entry
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *search_entry;
} WINDOW_AND_SEARCH_ENTRY;

and then in main:

GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *search_entry;

...

WINDOW_AND_SEARCH_ENTRY window_and_search_entry;
window_and_search_entry.window = window;
window_and_search_entry.search_entry = search_entry;
```

and that two:

```
g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(search_entry), "activate", G_CALLBACK(analyse), (gpointer) &window_and_search_entry);

g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(do_it_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(analyse), (gpointer) &window_and_search_entry);
```

And I want to create function which takes text, and window, makes some operations on it and if an error occurs print it out with other function which takes window as parameter

```
ELEMENT *analyse(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    //((WINDOW_AND_SEARCH_ENTRY *) user_data)->search_entry;
    GtkWidget *a = ((WINDOW_AND_SEARCH_ENTRY*)(user_data))->search_entry;
    const char *text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(a));
    g_print("%s\n", text);




    ELEMENT *heap[100];
    int index = 0;


    return heap[1];
}
```

I tried many variants but I get "Segmentation fault" after having something typed in entry_box followed by enter or button. I want to print the text to console. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Reason is that window_and_search_entry struct is not allocated, try allocate the struct with g_slice_new; Something occurs when you call analyse the function that the struct is not in the stack.

Comment: @Joel, the `window_and_search_entry` is a struct on the stack, it is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `analyse` callback requires `g_signal_connect`, not `g_signal_connect_swapped`. Also there is no need to cast pointers: the `G_CALLBACK()` macro already cast the whole function, so this would suffice:

```
ELEMENT *analyse(GtkWidget *widget, WINDOW_AND_SEARCH_ENTRY *data)
```

With `g_signal_connect_swapped` it would be:

```
ELEMENT *analyse(WINDOW_AND_SEARCH_ENTRY *data, GtkWidget *widget);
```

This swapped version is only a C convenience for already existing functions, e.g. you can do something like this:

```
g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(search_entry), "activate",
                         G_CALLBACK(g_print), "Activate signal called");
```